# Kong API Gateway - Reading request body in custom plugin

Tags: nginx, openresty, kong, lua-ngx-module, kong-plugin

I am trying to read the request body in a custom plugin by following [this url](https://docs.konghq.com/1.0.x/pdk/kong.request/#kongrequestget_bodymimetype-max_args)

```
  local data = kong.request.get_body()
  if data then
      kong.log(data)
  end
```

I am getting the following error

```
2019/03/14 21:57:55 [error] 14039#0: *45 lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/pdk/private/phases.lua:66: no phase in kong.ctx.core.phase
stack traceback:
coroutine 0:
        [C]: in function 'error'
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/pdk/private/phases.lua:66: in function 'check_phase'
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/pdk/request.lua:594: in function 'get_body'
        .../Apps/troop/kong/plugins/customlog/handler.lua:72: in function <.../Apps/troop/kong/plugins/customlog/handler.lua:62>, context: ngx.timer, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:8000
Can anyone help me understand the problem here? I need to log the request body in my plugin.
```

Can anyone help me understand the problem here?

I need to log the request body in my plugin.

Answer (score 1):

That call can only be called in the "rewrite, access or admin_api" phase.

Looking at your log output, the context you're trying to call it is **ngx.timer**, which is not even wrapped by Kong as one of its contexts. (More on that [here](https://docs.konghq.com/1.0.x/plugin-development/custom-logic/))

What you could do is call "kong.request.get_body()" in a phase that can call it, store it in a temp var (using "kong.ctx.plugin" object), and then use it in the "log" phase for said plugin.